Are garden gnomes Chukot Hagoyim
According to Halacha, are garden gnomes classified as Chukot Hagoyim, or not? I ask because on the one hand, they are not associated with idolatry nowadays, however they are a custom of non-Jewish origin and do not have a rational basis and arguably idolatrous origin and history.

https://www.asktherabbi.org/question/garden-gnomes-chukat-hagoyim/

https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/59424

See this Q&A What makes something "chukat goyim?"  and in particular this paragraph:
"Rabbi Feinstein says we follow the opinion of the Ran, that chukat goyim is only something that the Jews haven't done until now, AND it has something to do with paganism or sexual immodesty."
It appears that garden gnomes very definitely have pagan origins - see https://sunnydazedecor.com/blogs/news/the-complete-history-of-garden-gnomes-why-they-are-wonderful#:~:text=These%20were%20statues%20of%20the,to%20keep%20evil%20spirits%20away.
and in particular:
"However, the earliest gnome statuary descendants were used in ancient Rome. These were statues of the Roman gods and the most common one was Priapus, a god of fertility derived from Greek mythology.
"The gnome statue, and other statues like it, were used in gardens to ensure a bountiful harvest by protecting the animals and plants. They also were said to keep evil spirits away."
So that would endorse the conclusion give at https://www.asktherabbi.org/question/garden-gnomes-chukat-hagoyim/ cited by @Dov
"I am not familiar with any contemporary sources that address that particular issue. Rav Moshe Feinstein’s Teshuvah is normally used as the measuring rod for Chukas Hagoyim. Inside of his Teshuvah Rav Moshe writes that one of the issues is that of paganism. It is somewhat difficult to define whether garden gnomes today fall into that category – even though they certainly started off as a pagan concept – as I imagine that they are not manufactured today for pagan beliefs but simply to make money.
"However, having said that, I would not recommend that anyone put them in their gardens."
There are many who would ban garden gnomes on the grounds of taste; including the world famous Chelsea Flower Show of the UK's Royal Horticultural Society see https://www.standard.co.uk/hp/front/chelsea-flower-show-cracks-down-on-garden-gnomes-6769780.html and Chelsea Flower Show: Our love-hate relationship with garden gnomes
That could be the reason for the conclusion of the AskTheRabbi.org Team cited above: ". . . I would not recommend that anyone put them in their gardens."

As I understand it a downvote is give when the downvoter considers that an answer is "not useful". It is really unhelpful if downvoters do not explain why they consider an answer to be "not useful." In this case I must be honest in saying that I think my answer is a good one. In addition the OP accepted it.

I appreciate receiving an upvote to take me from -1 to 0. Thank you.

1 You did a great job!
